# Making Prediction with tensorflow's estimator.DNNRegressor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am quite new to tensorflow and in order to learn to use it I am currently trying to implement a very simple DNNRegressor that predicts the movement of an object in 2D but I can't seem to the the predict function to work.

for this purpose I have some Input data - x and y coordinates of the object in a number of previous time steps. I want the output to a reasonable estimation of the location the object if it continues to move in the same direction with the same speed.

I am using tensorflow version 1.8.0

My regressor is defined like this:

```
CSV_COLUMN_NAMES = ['X_0', 'X_1', 'X_2', 'X_3', 'X_4', 'Y_0', 'Y_1', 'Y_2', 'Y_3', 'Y_4', 'Y_5']

my_feature_columns = []
for key in columnNames:
     my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=key))


regressor = estimator.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
                                           label_dimension=1,
                                           hidden_units=hidden_layers,
                                           model_dir=MODEL_PATH,
                                           dropout=dropout,
                                           config=test_config)
```

my input is, like the one in the tensorflow tutorial on premade estimators, a dict with the column as key.
An example for this input can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/Strandtasche/af8b573c3b1be5bfbc3f02e08930e8c5).

regressor.train(*arguments*) and regressor.evaluate(*arguments*) seem to work just fine, but predict does not.

parallel to the code on the [tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/premade_estimators#making_predictions_inferring_from_the_trained_model) I tried to do this:

```
y_pred = regressor.predict(input_fn=eval_input_fn(X_test, labels=None, batch_size=1))
```

and it seems like that works as well.

The problem I'm facing now is that I can't get anything from that `y_pred` object.

when I enter `print(y_pred)` I get `<generator object Estimator.predict at 0x7fd9e8899888>` which would suggest to me that should be able to iterate over it but

```
    for elem in y_pred:
        print(elem)
```

results in `TypeError: unsupported callable`

Again, I'm quite new to this and I am sorry if the answer is obvious but I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input_fn` to `regressor.predict` should be a function. See the [definition](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNRegressor#predict):

> input_fn: A function that constructs the features.

You need to change your code to:

```
y_pred = regressor.predict(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
```

Comment: You're right about the problem - it is indeed the fact that the way I wrote this input_fn is definied as the output of my eval_input_fn and not the function itself.

I changed my code to 

`y_pred = regressor.predict(input_fn=lambda :eval_input_fn(X_test, labels=None, batch_size=1))`